# Turn a category into a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that gives as result some properties categorizedm but I need  every category to be turned into a column

This is my query:

```
SELECT hist_statusevents.eqmt,
       hist_exproot.shiftdate,
       hist_statusevents.category, 
       Sum(hist_statusevents.duration/3600) as Value
FROM Powerview.dbo.hist_eqmtlist hist_eqmtlist, 
     Powerview.dbo.hist_exproot hist_exproot,   
      Powerview.dbo.hist_statusevents hist_statusevents
WHERE hist_exproot.shiftindex = hist_statusevents.shiftindex And 
      hist_statusevents.shiftindex = hist_eqmtlist.shiftindex And 
      hist_statusevents.eqmt = hist_eqmtlist.eqmtid And 
      hist_statusevents.eqmt like 'MOTO%'
GROUP BY hist_statusevents.eqmt, 
         hist_exproot.shiftdate,
         hist_statusevents.category
```

This is the output of the query:

```
eqmt            shiftdate         category   Value
MOTO705         2011-01-22 00:00:00  5      13,9597222805023
MOTO706         2011-01-28 00:00:00  3      0,280277773737907
MOTO704         2011-02-17 00:00:00  6      8,92749977111816
MOTO705         2011-02-09 00:00:00  6      10,07972240448
MOTO703         2011-03-15 00:00:00  1      22,6561107933521
MOTO704         2011-03-11 00:00:00  5      24
MOTO706         2011-01-27 00:00:00  1      9,95361125469208
MOTO703         2011-03-16 00:00:00  6      3,79916667938232
MOTO704         2011-01-08 00:00:00  6      24
```

But i need to get the result as this:

```html
eqmt            shiftdate            1  2  3  4  5  6  7
MOTO706         2011-01-28 00:00:00  values for each category
MOTO704         2011-02-17 00:00:00  
MOTO705         2011-02-09 00:00:00  
MOTO703         2011-03-15 00:00:00
```

i've been trying with select case, but i cant get the structure works

Comment: Is there a limited and fixed amount of categories?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the category values are fixed and are in the range(1,7) then you can use case based aggregation like below
if the category values are dynamic, you need to use dynamic sql to do `pivot`

```
SELECT hist_statusevents.eqmt, 
       hist_exproot.shiftdate, 
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =1 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as '1',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =2 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as '2',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =3 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as '3',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =4 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as '4',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =5 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as '5',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =6 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as '6',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =7 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as '7'

FROM Powerview.dbo.hist_eqmtlist hist_eqmtlist, Powerview.dbo.hist_exproot hist_exproot, Powerview.dbo.hist_statusevents hist_statusevents
WHERE hist_exproot.shiftindex = hist_statusevents.shiftindex And hist_statusevents.shiftindex = hist_eqmtlist.shiftindex And hist_statusevents.eqmt = hist_eqmtlist.eqmtid And hist_statusevents.eqmt like 'MOTO%'
GROUP BY hist_statusevents.eqmt, hist_exproot.shiftdate
```

Comment: i get this error;


Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @Pipebritop, end was missing fro the case, try now

Comment: Great!!!  but I realized than the values didnt keep on group for example `eqmt shiftdate 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
MOTO703      2011-01-01 00:00:00 18,3538888692856 0 0 0 0 0 0
MOTO703      2011-01-01 00:00:00 0 0 0 0 0 5,64611101150513 0`

Comment: ahhhhh   for the same eqmt it repeats for every time it appears on a different category column

Comment: @Pipebritop, remvoe category from group by

Comment: i realized when you were writing, tnx